# clojure: devcards: separating out main app

Tags: clojure

### Situation

I am using clojure + figwheel + devcards.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7Z_g2fnEDg

Everything is great, except for the following problem:

- I can prototype UI components of my app. However, I don't want my full app to be inside a card.

  So in particular, I want the following:

localhost:8000/cards.html <-- show me all my namespaces + devcards
localhost:8000/app.html <-- don't show me any devcards; don't show me the directory of devcards; just run my app

### Question:

How do I get this setup? Almost everything I have read is about *how to use devcards* not how to setup a separate devcards vs main app distinction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much the default already for the devcards template (e.g. `lein new devcards my-app`).

Have more than one build in your `project.clj`.  One for the devcards (note the different paths and the figwheel config).  The `dev` is pretty much the default.

[(This code is from the template)](https://github.com/bhauman/devcards-template/blob/master/src/leiningen/new/devcards/project.clj):

```
 ; ...
 :builds [{:id "devcards"
           :source-paths ["src"]
           :figwheel { :devcards true  ;; <- note this
                      ;; :open-urls will pop open your application
                      ;; in the default browser once Figwheel has
                      ;; started and complied your application.
                      ;; Comment this out once it no longer serves you.
                      :open-urls ["http://localhost:3449/cards.html"]}
           :compiler { :main       "xxx.core"
                      :asset-path "js/compiled/devcards_out"
                      :output-to  "resources/public/js/compiled/xxx_devcards.js"
                      :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/devcards_out"
                      :source-map-timestamp true }}
          {:id "dev"
           :source-paths ["src"]
           :figwheel true
           :compiler {:main       "xxx.core"
                      :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                      :output-to  "resources/public/js/compiled/xxx.js"
                      :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                      :source-map-timestamp true }}
           ;...
```

Now you need two different HTML files.  One you are already using (the `cards.html`) and your `app.html` (or what the template is using: `index.html`).  They load:

```
<script src="/js/compiled/xxx_devcards.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The other:

```
<script src="/js/compiled/xxx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note, that those are the two from `:output-to`.

Run this setup with `lein figwheel dev devcards`.  Open both the index and the cards in your browser.  Enjoy.

In practice it might be even better to separate that a bit more.  You can do this, by either using different ns for your `:main` - or you can use multiple `:source-paths`.

Comment: 1. Awesome thanks! 2. My bad -- I somehow setup devcardds without using "lein tempalte" (I think I just copied stuff around). 3. Yes, setting up two separate "compile profiles" is the correct approach. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

How I solved this with only one build:

1) In the HTML create a global variable that indicates whether devcards should be loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var showDevcards = true; // or false
</script>
```

2) In your initial ClojureScript namespace check this variable:

```
(if js/showDevcards
   (devcards/init!)
   (init!)) ;; what you had previously
```

Comment: Are you able to tell if this does not add size to the `:advanced` build then `showDevcards` is true?

Comment: @nha I have two different initial files for dev and production by loading a `src-cljs-dev` source directory directory during development and `src-cljs-prod` at build time. Both directories contain a slightly adapted initial ClojureScript namespace. Devcards is only present during development. See this example: https://github.com/borkdude/lein2boot

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Accepted other answer as (1) it was earlier (2) I am using lein, and (3) it works. However, the succintness of this solution is amazing and I'm ever more tempted to use Boot. [Lein seems way too magical.]

Comment: @eavdb It's not specific to Boot, the same thing could be achieved with Leiningen. Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned Boot. In fact, I removed the reference to it.